# how to implement the struts project into my own project?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1, struts-config, struts-validation

As a trainee I have been working on a project, a java web application. Till now i have used javascript and `jquery` for validations but now I also know `struts 1.x and struts 2`   and want to apply that instead of `javascript`... So I have to copy all the files from my struts app. into my project folder in net beans ... I mean all the specific file like the one's in `web-inf` i have to copy them exactly ?
Or there's another way of doing it in net beans like `merge projects` or something ?

Comment: As stated this question makes no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: simply put, till now my web application uses javascript for form field validations. Now i want to implement struts, so is there any method to merge projects ? or i have to include the struts library and then create new action classes and formbeans in my project again ? in context of NETBEANS

Comment: Just copy the files; what's the issue?

Comment: i was having issues with some libraries not being included, now it is working ! Just copied them !